# Pythonic way to return a list initialized in a function?

Tags: python

I am writing a function that does parsing on a file and builds a list.  I can think of 2 ways to do this and I'm wondering if one of them is considered more Pythonic.

In the first approach, the function returns the list.

```
def initList(fname):
   mylist = []
   # process fname & build list
   return mylist

if __name__ == "__main__":
   list_a = initList('someFile')
```

In the 2nd way, knowing that lists are mutable objects and therefore if passed as an argument into a function any changes made in the function change the actual list gives this:

```
def initList(fname, mylist):
   # process fname & build list

if __name__ == "__main__":
   list_a = []
   initList('someFile', list_a)
```

I'm leaning toward the first way since it makes it clear to the reader that the function is initializing the list.  But the 2nd way seems a little more general in the sense that if initList() adds to the list using mylist.append() calls it could be reused to add elements to a list that already exists, while the 1st approach can't.

Is there a consensus on what the best practice would be here?

Comment: Usually I'd return a new list, but I guess it depends on the use case. if you are passing in a list, modifying the list in place might be best (like `random.shuffle`). Python doesn't have the restriction of other languages and you can return more than one list easily

Comment: Undoubtedly, the first way.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your needs.

If you should *always* start out with an empty list there is no point in having it as a parameter.

If, on the other hand, you may want to add items to an already defined list you should take it as a parameter.

If you want to support both you can do this:

```
def initList(fname, mylist = None):
    if mylist is None:
        mylist = []
    # process fname and build list
    return mylist
```

That supports both

```
list_a = initList('someFile')
```

and

```
list_a = []
initList('someFile', list_a)
```

Note that you can always do this too:

```
list_a = []
list_a.extend(initList('someFile'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is totally subjective :) but since your function is called `initList`, it makes sense to use the second method as you are passing the list to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think the most Pythonic solution would be to write your function as a generator, separating logic specific to the containing datatype from that for producing the elements, and making client code more explicit about the collection's type (while also being more flexible).

In general though, I think people should treat data structures as immutable as much as possible. Always clearer and less error prone. The only justification I can think of for the mutable list approach would be efficiency, in which case a) the generator approach is even more appropriate and b) you probably just shouldn't be writing that code in Python.